# HTML5/CSS: How to prevent stacking inside a div?

Tags: css, html

I suppose that this is already in some topic, but I couldn't find the answer that I'm looking for.
I have a header that looks like this:

[image]

And its code is the following one:

```
<header>
    <section id="login">
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </section>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left" id="image-maintitle">
            <img src="~/Images/DirecTV.jpg" width="70" height="43" />
            <div id="main-title">
                <h1 class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("Disponibilidad de Señal", "Index", "Home")</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SPDCSSUrl"]" target="_blank">Ir a sistema de monitoreo</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The problem is that both div are stacking when I reach a width of 850px, like you can see in this image:

[image]

I tried setting up a min-width in **content-wrapper** class or in "header" tag, but isn't working. The strange thing is that when I try to select "inspect element" of this div on the browser, I can't do it... only I can do it with the elements on the inside.

Here is my CSS document of this classes:

```
.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section
{
    display: block;
}

ul#menu
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    text-align: right;
}

.content-wrapper {
    min-width: 1000px !important;
}
```

**I want to hide the right div behind the scrollbar when its container reaches 1000px of width.**

Is there another way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Just set a media query to the "right div", like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    #right-div {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

This will only show the right div when the screen resolution is > 1000px in width.

Comment: This was an excellent answer! but I won't considered that the element needs to be shown by scrolling the page (the error was mine) because it is a link to another page. Do you know how to prevent the stacking without making "disappear" this element? (sorry for my mistake)

Comment: Set both inner divs to 'width:50%;' and float them both. However, considering that you have quite some text in both divs it probably looks funny on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `max-width` instead of `min-width`? `min-width` specifies things you want to show if the window is **a certain size or larger**, whereas `max-width` specifies things you want to show if the window is at a **certain size or smaller**.

Comment: The thing is that the page doesn't need to have a max-width setting because it has to grow up in different resolutions, that's why I didn't tried it.

Comment: @MauroBilotti In that case I would set the div to hide by default and then only show in the `min-width` cases at or above **800px**.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, but the right div is a link to another page and I can't hide it, when I meant "hide" I wanted to say "hide behind the scroll", so when the user needs to click this link, he has to move the scroll bar to the right...are you understand?

Comment: @MauroBilotti So you want that container div to have a fixed length, with the rest of the site being responsive and resizing to match the browser window?

Comment: Yes, more or less, because I want this container div to grow up (I don't want to set a fixed length), but I also need that when it reaches 1000px of minimun, its elements inside doesn't stack each other.

Comment: @MauroBilotti In that case, I would set a different fixed property value for this div at each break point where you would use a new media query. So for **1000px or more**, you have it set the way it is now, and for between, say, **1000px** and **768px**, you have it set to a smaller, fixed length. For a width between **768px** and **480px**, you might have it set to an even smaller fixed length.


I would start with the smallest resolution first, then build up, unless you know your target audience is primarily desktop-based.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, but i'm kind of confused because I always solved this kind of problem by using a **min-width** property. I don't know why both divs are still stacking each other. Thanks anyway Tyler, you have been really helpful!

Comment: @MauroBilotti Just be careful if you implement a solution using only `min-width` or only `max-width` multiple times, because they will often override each other! Ex: `max-width: 1000px {display:none}` will override a `max-width: 768px {display: inherit}` because the 1000px value includes the 768px value, since 768 is not bigger than 1000 (read: 768 is *within* the maximum value of 1000px). Hope you don't have too much trouble fixing this!

Comment: This is truth! Probably the problem is that some class is overriding another or something like that. This kind of bugs often are difficult to find... but I don't have other choice! Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the CSS display property correctly.

Try `display:inline-block;` or `display:block;` in the css for each of the elements.

Also setting the `max-width:1000px;` in the right div

to do this inline use `<div style="display:block">`

Edit after seeing the Css: Try changing the widths to suit your setup

```
.float-left {
float: left;
position:relative;
width:80%;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( . Still the elements are stacking...thanks anyway!

Comment: You may also need to float the right div to the right otherwise the div will sit next to (or under if its too large) the first one.

Comment: The "float-right" class does it! This class only specifies a "float: right;" property.

Comment: hmm It looks like the problem could be that you are trying to fit too much on one line when they get too large try reducing the width and max-width of each until they sit next to each other. I'm afraid its very difficult to help you test this one due to not knowing the rest of your css setup. What is the position property set as? its best if its relative.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the document to expose all css class involved in this line :)

Comment: Here is an example of how I have dealt with this issue before its been made really basic so hopefully it helps http://jsfiddle.net/mr4Nk/9/